# how to create a bootable ISO image

Tags: boot

I have a Windows 7 ISO image. I am trying install it in a virtual machine. The virtual machine which is created by the VirtualBox software is asking for a bootable iso image?
I do not have any CD/DVD in this computer. I have an external drive on which the ISO image is currently present.

How do I create a bootable iso image? Is there a freeware to do this?

Comment: Where did the W7 iso come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the ISO through Virtual Box.

When the VM starts up, it will read the iso just like a DVD.

Comment: Yes, the ISO should already have a bootsector if it is a real Windows 7 image.

Answer (score 0):

It depends the kind of Windows 7 ISO you have. And you said "image" so I make the assumption it's an ISO. But what is the format of your image?

Is it a genuine, untouched one? If it is, it's always already bootable. Microsoft doesn't make jokes by selling non-bootable Windows CD.

If it's a modded one, some of them are specifically destinated to boot in virtual machines, and some are destinated as a medium to install W7 on a computer.

If you had your Windows 7 from an unlegitimate or unofficial source (torrents for instance), they are not always bootable, some works in virtual machines, but not for installing the OS, and some are not good to use with virtual machines, they crash, maybe some files are missing, I don't know.